# Python Pyside Thread stop/kill - that executes mutliline code using exec

Tags: python, multithreading, pyside

The problem I am having is with stopping a thread forcefully in python. The thread's job is to execute python code that the user inputs. I want to be able to kill the thread regardless of what it is doing when the user pushed a button on the Gui.

```
class WorkerThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, code):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.mutex = QtCore.QMutex()
        self.code = compile(code,'<string>','exec')

    def run(self):
        self.mutex.lock()
        exec self.code
        self.mutex.unlock()
```

What is the best way to kill the thread?
I have tried using WorkerThread.terminate() but that terminates the entire program, even the main gui.

Or is there a better way to execute the python code?

**Edited:**
I researched some more and I couldn't find a way to safety terminate thread without crashing the main process, so I am going to use process from the multiprocessing package of python to create a process that executes the code and using [psutil](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/) to suspend/terminate the process from a thread.